# Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, valueerror

I have two dataframes as follows:

`leader`:

```
0 11
1  8
2  5
3  9
4  8
5  6
[6065 rows x 2 columns]
```

`DatasetLabel`:

```
   0  1 ....  7  8    9   10   11   12  
0  A  J ....  1  2    5  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  B  K ....  3  4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
[4095 rows x 14 columns]
```

The Information dataset column names 0 to 6 are `DatasetLabel` about data and 7 to 12 are indexes that refer to the first column of `leader` Dataframe.

I want to create dataset where instead of the indexes in `DatasetLabel` dataframe, I have the value of each index from the `leader` dataframe, which is `leader.iloc[index,1]`.

How can I do it using python features?

The output should look like:

`DatasetLabel`:

```
   0  1 ....  7  8    9   10   11   12  
0  A  J ....  8  5    6  NaN  NaN  NaN  
1  B  K ....  9  8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I have come up with the following, but I get an error:

```py
for column in DatasetLabel.ix[:, 8:13]:
    DatasetLabel[DatasetLabel[column].notnull()] = leader.iloc[DatasetLabel[DatasetLabel[column].notnull()][column].values, 1]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your expected output?  It's not really clear what you're asking.  It seems like you want to match values from `DatasetLabel` to `leader`, but columns 7-12 have different values for each row.  So which one do you want to use for matching?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `apply` to index into `leader` and exchange values with `DatasetLabel`, although it's not very pretty.

One issue is that Pandas won't let us index with `NaN`.  Converting to `str` provides a workaround.  But that creates a second issue, namely, column `9` is of type `float` (because `NaN` is `float`), so `5` becomes `5.0`.  Once it's a string, that's `"5.0"`, which will fail to match the index values in `leader`.  We can remove the `.0`, and then this solution will work - but it's a bit of a hack.

With `DatasetLabel` as:

```
   Unnamed:0  0  1  7  8    9  10  11  12
0          0  A  J  1  2  5.0 NaN NaN NaN
1          1  B  K  3  4  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

And `leader` as:

```
   0   1
0  0  11
1  1   8
2  2   5
3  3   9
4  4   8
5  5   6
```

Then:

```
cols = ["7","8","9","10","11","12"]
updated = DatasetLabel[cols].apply(
    lambda x: leader.loc[x.astype(str).str.split(".").str[0], 1].values, axis=1)

updated
     7    8    9  10  11  12
0  8.0  5.0  6.0 NaN NaN NaN
1  9.0  8.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Now we can `concat` the unmodified columns (which we'll call `original`) with `updated`:

```
original_cols = DatasetLabel.columns[~DatasetLabel.columns.isin(cols)]
original = DatasetLabel[original_cols]
pd.concat([original, updated], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Unnamed:0  0  1    7    8    9  10  11  12
0          0  A  J  8.0  5.0  6.0 NaN NaN NaN
1          1  B  K  9.0  8.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Note: It may be clearer to use `concat` here, but here's another, cleaner way of merging `original` and `updated`, using `assign`:

```
DatasetLabel.assign(**updated)
```

Answer (score 7):

The [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.2/pandas/core/indexing.py#L1828-L1882) shows that this error occurs when you try to broadcast a list-like object (numpy array, list, set, tuple etc.) to multiple columns or rows but didn't specify the index correctly. Of course, list-like objects don't have custom indices like pandas objects, so it usually causes this error.

Solutions to common cases:

1. **You want to assign the same values across multiple columns at once.** In other words, you want to change the values of certain columns using a list-like object whose (a) length doesn't match the number of columns or rows and (b) dtype doesn't match the dtype of the columns they are being assigned to.<sup>1</sup> An illustration may make it clearer. If you try to make the transformation below:

   [image: first]

   using a code similar to the one below, this error occurs:

   ```py
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, 9], 'B': [2, 6, 10], 'C': [3, 7, 11], 'D': [4, 8, 12]})
   df.loc[:2, ['C','D']] = [100, 200.2, 300]
   ```

   **Solution:** Duplicate the list/array/tuple, transpose it (either using `T` or `zip()`) and assign to the relevant rows/columns.<sup>2</sup>

   ```py
   df.loc[:2, ['C','D']] = np.tile([100, 200.2, 300], (len(['C','D']), 1)).T 
   # if you don't fancy numpy, use zip() on a list
   # df.loc[:2, ['C','D']] = list(zip(*[[100, 200.2, 300]]*len(['C','D'])))
   ```

2. **You want to assign the same values to multiple rows at once.** If you try to make the following transformation

   [image: second]

   using a code similar to the following:

   ```py
   df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 5, 9], 'B': [2, 6, 10], 'C': [3, 7, 11], 'D': [4, 8, 12]})
   df.loc[[0, 1], ['A', 'B', 'C']] = [100, 200.2]
   ```

   **Solution:** To make it work as expected, we must convert the list/array into a Series with the correct index:

   ```py
   df.loc[[0, 1], ['A', 'B', 'C']] = pd.Series([100, 200.2], index=[0, 1])
   ```

   A common sub-case is if the row indices come from using a boolean mask. N.B. This is the case in the OP. In that case, just use the mask to filter `df.index`:

   ```py
   msk = df.index < 2
   df.loc[msk, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = [100, 200.2]                                 # <--- error
   df.loc[msk, ['A', 'B', 'C']] = pd.Series([100, 200.2], index=df.index[msk]) # <--- OK
   ```

3. **You want to store the same list in some rows of a column.** An illustration of this case is:

   [image: third]

   **Solution:** Explicitly construct a Series with the correct indices.

   ```py
   # for the case on the left in the image above
   df['D'] = pd.Series([[100, 200.2]]*len(df), index=df.index)

   # latter case
   df.loc[[1], 'D'] = pd.Series([[100, 200.2]], index=df.index[[1]])
   ```

---

<sup>1: Here, we tried to assign a list containing a float to int dtype columns, which contributed to this error being raised. If we tried to assign a list of ints (so that the dtypes match), we'd get a different error: `ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,3)` which can also be solved by the same method as above.</sup>

<sup>2: An error related to this one `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray` occurs if the object being assigned is a numpy array and there's a shape mismatch. That one is often solved either using `np.tile` or simply transposing the array.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because Pandas is trying to set multiple values in one cell. You can fix it by converting the list to a single value, like a string or a tuple:

```py
for column in DatasetLabel.ix[:, 8:13]:
    DatasetLabel[DatasetLabel[column].notnull()] = tuple(leader.iloc[DatasetLabel[DatasetLabel[column].notnull()][column].values, 1])
```