# Replacing pandas cell value with a new list generates ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to update the value of a cell that takes a list with a new updated list. However, when I try to replace the value using `.iloc` I get a `ValueError`.

```py
d = {'title':['GrownUps', 'Toy Story', 'Toy Story', 'Avatar', 'Avatar', 'Avatar'], 'year': [["Hello", "World"],
                                                                                            ["Not", "Object", "!"],
                                                                                            1995, 2000, 2005, 2006]}
dataset_SO=pd.DataFrame(d)

dataset_SO.iloc[0,1]=["hi", "cat", "dog"] #this line produces the ValueError
```

> ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

I know it might be a silly question, however trying to make this `["hi", "cat", "dog"]` an object, like `np.object0(["hi", "cat", "dog"])`. Or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48000225/must-have-equal-len-keys-and-value-when-setting-with-an-iterable) didn't help me to solve my issue.

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? I cannot reproduce your error when copy-paste your code with pandas 1.1.4.

Comment: @ndclt I use pandas 1.2.1.

Comment: I copied your example above exactly using pandas 1.2.2 and it worked fine.

Comment: My neither. I cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: I do not get any errors when running your code. It may be the python or pandas version. Can you update pandas (pip install -U pandas) and try again.

Comment: Yeah guys I will update pandas version. My python version is 3.9.1

Comment: @Jorge and to the rest indeed, upgrading to pandas 1.2.2 fixed the error. Strange that it was not referred somewhere such a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide as to how to update packages in python

> [Update python packages](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-update-all-python-packages/)

Comment: Thank you for the guide Jorge. Can I ask something else also related. If I create a pandas dataframe (version1 2.1) and save it. Then upgrading to pandas 1.2.2 should I have the dataframe created again with the new version to fix any bugs?

Comment: How do you saved the dataframe? Traditionally is good to save it as csv, but depends on your need/requirements.

Comment: with ```pd.to_pickle``` with pd being the pandas 1.2.1 version. So I assume I have to recreate it with version 1.2.2

Comment: Got it. Not sure what changes to the saving part have been done between the versions of pandas that you are dealing with are. Suggest try to open the dataframe and see what happens. Hopefully the format dis not change.

Comment: The format is not changed but the little trick with the dummy dataset above does not work for the dataset created and saved in in pandas 1.2.1 even if I updated the pandas to 1.2.2

Comment: I am not following. The issue from this question is not related to the way you are saving the dataframe to a file. You may need to rerun everything in the new version including the saving step

Comment: Yeah that's for sure something that I will try. But the dataframe had a tedious and long process to be made. I guess I have to rerun the code again. I wanted to make sure that I didn't miss anything.